# Change progress bar in warsaw and infolines

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, header-footer, themes

I am trying hard without success to change the **progress bar** at top of each slide to exactly like below  while using **warsaw theme** and outertheme of **infolines**.

(If I remove inforlines then my desired layout of page number etc gets changed)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}


}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} %For TexLive
\usepackage{comment}
\bibliography{references}
\usepackage[disable,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[\date{\today} ]{Title  } 

\subtitle{heading}
\author[au]{author} % Your name
\institute[]
{  
}
\date[]{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

    \section{Test section one}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \section{Test section one}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the other way round and select a theme with your desired headline and simply copy over the footline from `infolines`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{

\definecolor{bluecern}{HTML}{0053A1}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=bluecern}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=bluecern}
}
\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
}
\makeatother


\title[\date{\today}]{Title} 
\subtitle{heading}
\author[au]{author} 
\institute[]{}
\date[]{\today} 

\begin{document}

    \section{Test section one}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \section{Test section one}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Test subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to include `\mode<presentation> {}` too ?

Comment: @kaka see my edit