# How to remove brackets?

Tags: beamer

I wanted to add a bar progress to my slides, and following your suggestions, I found this useful post: [Change progress bar in warsaw and infolines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323289/change-progress-bar-in-warsaw-and-infolines)... and it works very well.

But, as you can see on the picture below, there are brackets in the section entitled "Questions".

[image]

How could I remove them? This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>{

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
 \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\definecolor{lapislazuli}{rgb}{0.15, 0.38, 0.61}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=lapislazuli}
}
\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
}
\makeatother
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\title[Searching for a progress bar template]{Searching for a progress bar template}
\author[] {Questions}
\institute[Questions]{Chapter}
\date[] {Notions}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    Explanations.
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    ...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Definitions}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See if the package `beamerthemeprogressbar` can help you: http://recherche.noiraudes.net/resources/LaTeX/svn/packages/beamerthemeprogressbar-0.42/

Comment: I can't place those files in my library in so far as there is no such place in /Applications/TeX on my Mac. How could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
\author {Questions}
%\institute[Questions]{Chapter}
```

instead of

```
\author[] {Questions}
\institute[Questions]{Chapter}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>{

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
 \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\definecolor{lapislazuli}{rgb}{0.15, 0.38, 0.61}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=lapislazuli}
}
\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
}
\makeatother
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\title[Searching for a progress bar template]{Searching for a progress bar template}
\author {Questions}
%\institute[Questions]{Chapter}
\date[] {Notions}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    Explanations.
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    ...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Definitions}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, except if I write this: \author{Questions}
\institute[]{Chapter}

Comment: It works for me with MikTeX. Which engine do you use?

Comment: Thanks, it work. And if I write this:\author{Questions}
\institute[]{Chapter}, I keep the benefit to use also \institute. (I use TEXShop).

Comment: Normally these fields are not intended to be used as you do (the author is you and the institute is the place where you work). I suppose there must be another way to do it.

Comment: @AndréC My sincere appreciation for you.

Comment: @Sebastiano You are the most pleasant of all the participants with a kind word for everyone. I appreciate it very much. Thank you.